# Regex for Matching Input like "abc > 10, cba < 100, ..." for Pattern in HTML Input

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input

I have an Input field in an HTML Document. It should not accept any input except input in this format **abc > 10, a1 < 100, a2 >= 20,** .. and so on.

I have tried various ways. Closest pattern that I could come up with is this **([A-Za-z0-9]+\s[<>=!==]{1,2}\s[A-Za-z0-9]+[, ]{0,1})+** . However, with this pattern the input field can also accept input of format abc > 10a1 < 10 without ','  or abc > 10,a1 < 100 without single space after comma.

How can I write a regex that will ensure that between two or more statments like abc > 10, a1 < 100, c1 >= 20 there is always a comma and single space charater separating these statements and if there is only one statement then there is no comma required at the end?

Thanks

Comment: `,` is a comma, not a semicolon. Did you mean `;`?

Comment: Yes, I meant comma. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regexp first tests one single entry without the comma and then zero or more entries with the comma.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+ [>|<]=? \d+(, [A-Za-z0-9]+ [>|<]=? \d+)*$
```

The structure is:

```
^ : begins with
[A-Za-z0-9]+ : one or more combination of numbers or letters
[>|<] : one of either < or >
=? : zero or one occurrence of =
\d+ : one or more numbers
(, pattern)* : zero or more occurences of the same pattern but starting with a comma
$ : ends with
```

To acommodate for decimal numbers:

```
Za-z0-9]+ [>|<]=? \d+(\.\d+)?(, [A-Za-z0-9]+ [>|<]=? \d+(\.\d+)?)*$
```

The relevant part is:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

This says, one or more digits and optionally a group consisting of a period plus one or more digits. Grouping makes sure that if you have the dot, you also get at least one digit after it.

The problem with `\d+\.?\d+` is, you're only making the period optional but now you're requiring at least one digit **twice** which will make a single number like **5** fail this part.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Just wondering, if I want accommodate decimal numbers as well, not just digits, would it be the right way to do it?
^[A-Za-z0-9]+ [>|<]=? \d+\.?\d+(, [A-Za-z0-9]+ [>|<]=? \d+\.?\d+)*$

Comment: The problem I see with \d+\.?\d+ is, you're saying zero or one dot but the \d+ at the right will still expect at least one digit. If you had only \d+\d+ you can see a single digit will fail. Instead you want to group the dot with an extra digit like this: (\.\d+)? I'll add an edit to the answer.

Comment: Edited the answer and tried to explain it a little better, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

I guess, maybe

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*[=<>]{1,2}\s*\d+\s*,\s*)+(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*[=<>]{1,2}\s*\d+\s*)$
```

might be close to what you have in mind.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/8zK3Nm/1/)

---

#### Method 2

A bit more restricted version would be,

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*(?:>|<|<=|>=)\s*\d+\s*,\s*)+(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*(?:>|<|<=|>=)\s*\d+\s*)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PK7RBv/1/)

---

#### Method 3

Then if you'd wish to add other comparison operators, you can for instance modify the expression:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*(?:>|<|<=|>=|={1,3})\s*\d+\s*,\s*)+(?:[a-z0-9]+\s*(?:>|<|<=|>=|={1,3})\s*\d+\s*)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/N1Sk6k/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your regex to look for one or more expressions, with either a trailing comma and space or end-of-string after each expression:

```js
let str = ['abc > 10, a1 < 100, a2 >= 20',
'abc > 10a1 < 10',
'abc > 10,a1 < 100'];

str.map(s => console.log(s + ' is ' + (s.match(/^([a-z][a-z0-9]+\s*([><]=?|[!=]=)\s*\d+(, |$))+$/i) ? '' : 'not ') + 'ok'));
```

Note that I have corrected the part of your regex that looks for the operator to

```
([><]=?|[!=]=)
```

which will match *only* `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=` or `==`.

I've also assumed that you want variables to start with a letter and not a digit so I've made the variable part of the regex

```
[a-z][a-z0-9]+
```

If you're happy for variables to start with a digit, you can remove the `[a-z]` part.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is 90% good! The only mistake is the `[, ]{0,1}` at the end.

I think what you meant is `0 or 1 occurence of 'a comma then a space'` but `[, ]{0,1}` actually means `a comma, a space, or none`.

You can use `(, ){0,1}`, which can be simplified to `(, )?` and it works ;)

Also make sure you surround your regex with `^` and `$` else it would match wrong inputs because it would match parts of the input. You want to check the match based on the whole input.